# Condition for Bundle Existence

Tags: android

I am developing an android application .
Here is the first activity part.

```
Intent i =new Intent(Title.this,mydataview.class);

Bundle backPack =new Bundle();

backPack.putString("answer",setrsDolr); //setting a string in bundle

i.putExtras(backPack);

startActivity(i);

Here is second activity part

Bundle gotrsdolr =getIntent().getExtras();

                      h=gotrsdolr.getString("answer");


                    AmountsHolder am =new AmountsHolder(mydataview.this); //database    

                                     am.openn(); 
                      am.createnntry(h); //saving a string value
                      am.closse();

                      if(){

            AmountsHolder am1 =new AmountsHolder(mydataview.this);  
                          am1.openn(); 
                    rsdolrhol=am1.getDData();
                          am1.closse();
              dataviewall(rsdolrhol);   //method for setting text 
                }else{
            dataviewall(h);     

                }
```

What condition should i use in `if()` condition if my
 " `Bundle gotrsdolr =getIntent().getExtras();` " doesn't contain anything .else part is running perfect.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple and clean

```
 if(getIntent().hasExtra("answer")){
    condition here
 }
```

Comment: he is using a bundle. hasExtra works only if you put data directly inside the Itent

Answer (score 0):

`getString` from `Bundle` returns `null` if it does not contain nothing for that key

```
Bundle gotrsdolr =getIntent().getExtras();
if (gotrsdolr != null) {
  h=gotrsdolr.getString("answer");
  if (h != null) {
  }
}
```